# Node json2xls wont send file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json2xls

according to the documentation [json2xls](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2xls)

i should be able to do something like this:

```
   router.route('/api2/course/session/attending')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        var jsonArr = [{
            foo: 'bar',
            qux: 'moo',
            poo: 123,
            stux: new Date()
        },
            {
                foo: 'bar',
                qux: 'moo',
                poo: 345,
                stux: new Date()
            }];
        res.xls('data.xlsx', jsonArr);
    });
```

And then my client should download the `xls` file

However this is not happening.

My headers are as follow:

[image]

But the response is empty.

Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have this line `app.use(json2xls.middleware);`

Comment: @Subburaj Yes i do And im not getting any error messages either

Comment: @Subburaj the sheet is not empty

Comment: Then?? Is there any data??

Comment: @Subburaj i cant see the data because its not even downloading i get no file to download